# xamarin forms add duplicate stacklayout object to a scrollView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, scrollview

**Introduction**

I am new to C# programming, and have just started learning Xamarin Forms. I'm using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows to make a cross-platform app.

**Current Situation**

I have created a TabbedPage called Buy,it has a contentPage called BuyAnimals.

The ContentPage needs to have a ScrollView which has a single StackLayout as its child.

The StackLayout has 3 children which are Frames.

Inside each frame, there's supposed to be a StackLayout called animalStack.

The animalStack has many children made from StackLayout.

**The Problem.**

If I use that same animalStack as the content for each of the three Frames, only the last frame displays the contents of the animalStack while the other two frames show nothing.

Why aren't the other frames showing a duplicate of the information being show in the last frame? How can I make them show the information?

**My code is as show below.**

`public partial class Buy : TabbedPage
    {
        public Buy ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        var animalItemIdStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Post ID: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal ID"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        var animalUserIdStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "user ID: "},
                new Label { Text = "Posting userID"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        var animalBreedStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Breed: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's breed"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        var animalGenderStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Gender: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's gender"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalAgeStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Age: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's age"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalColorStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Color: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's color"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalPriceStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Price: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's price"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalLocationStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Location: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal owner's location"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalEmailStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Location: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's location"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalPhoneStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Phone: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal owner's phone"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalDatePostedStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Posted: "},
                new Label { Text = "Posted date"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };
        var animalLastEditStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Last Edit: "},
                new Label { Text = "Last Edited date"}
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        var animalStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                animalItemIdStack,
                animalUserIdStack,
                animalBreedStack,
                animalGenderStack,
                animalAgeStack,
                animalColorStack,
                animalPriceStack,
                animalLocationStack,
                animalEmailStack,
                animalEmailStack,
                animalPhoneStack,
                animalDatePostedStack,
                animalLastEditStack
            },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
        };

        var animalFrame = new Frame();
        animalFrame.Content = animalStack;

        var animalFrame2 = new Frame();
        animalFrame2.Content = animalStack;

        var animalFrame3 = new Frame();
        animalFrame3.Content = animalStack;

        var animalFullStack = new StackLayout();

        animalFullStack.Children.Add(animalFrame);
        animalFullStack.Children.Add(animalFrame2);
        animalFullStack.Children.Add(animalFrame3);

        var animalScrollView = new ScrollView();
        animalScrollView.Content = animalFullStack;

        BuyAnimals.Content = animalScrollView;


    }
}`
```

I'd really appreciate your input.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't add the same instance of a view to a layout multiple times.  You need to create a new instance instead.

Comment: Seems like some properties of the StackLayout object (and others similars) are defined/calculated when they are shown based on his parent, so the same of it instance can't have multiple parents.

Comment: Why are you trying to reuse the same instance?

Comment: Although, in this specific case, I guess you may use a ListView and define your layout as an ItemTemplate ViewCell. I will answer with some code to you to test if it fits (I really recommend you use bindings too)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that is it what you wanna do:

```
public partial class Buy (...){
    InitalizeComponent();
    Content = GetContent();
}

public View GetContent()
{
    var animalItemIdStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Post ID: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal ID"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };

    var animalUserIdStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "user ID: "},
                new Label { Text = "Posting userID"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };

    var animalBreedStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Breed: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's breed"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };

    var animalGenderStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Gender: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's gender"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalAgeStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Age: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's age"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalColorStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Color: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's color"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalPriceStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Price: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's price"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalLocationStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Location: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal owner's location"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalEmailStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Location: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal's location"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalPhoneStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Phone: "},
                new Label { Text = "Animal owner's phone"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalDatePostedStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Posted: "},
                new Label { Text = "Posted date"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };
    var animalLastEditStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Last Edit: "},
                new Label { Text = "Last Edited date"}
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };

    var animalStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Children =
            {
                animalItemIdStack,
                animalUserIdStack,
                animalBreedStack,
                animalGenderStack,
                animalAgeStack,
                animalColorStack,
                animalPriceStack,
                animalLocationStack,
                animalEmailStack,
                animalEmailStack,
                animalPhoneStack,
                animalDatePostedStack,
                animalLastEditStack
            },
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };

    var animalFrame = new Frame();
    animalFrame.Content = animalStack;


    var listView = new ListView();
    listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        return new ViewCell { View = animalFrame };
    });
    listView.ItemsSource = new List<object>()
            {
                new object(),
                new object(),
                new object(),
            };

    var contentStack = new StackLayout();
    contentStack.Children.Add(listView);

    return contentStack;
}
```

You'll need to complement this method with bindings.
See [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) about bindings and [this one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating/) about listview templating.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks.This worked. Had to add  `listView.HasUnevenRows = true` after creation of the listView object to show the remaining labels. Cheers mate. You have saved a mate in Tanzania.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Sorry by forget about 'HasUnevenRows', this is often necessary, really. You can count on me if you need help =)